# pd.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have used the following code to remove the default formating from the header in pandas.

```
pd.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None
```

It was working previously, but now I am getting following error.

```
pd.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pandas.io.formats' has no attribute 'excel'
```

What could be the possible reason and solution? Are there any alternate method for this?

Thanks.

I have tried updating Pandas. But that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried on pandas <2 as well as pandas >2, it is working in both pandas versions.

This should be the correct **import**:

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None
```

related git : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19386#issuecomment-851653196

Answer (score 0):

Some recent changes...

You can try both this ways, with the most recent versions to this day:

--> First one:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.formats import excel
excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None
(...)
df.to_excel('excel.xlsx')
```

--> Second one:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

df.to_excel('excel.xlsx',index=False, engine='openpyxl')
wb = load_workbook('excel.xlsx')

sheet = wb.active

for cell in sheet[1]:
    cell.font = cell.font.copy(bold=False)

wb.save('excel.xlsx')
```